# How to list all files changed after merge a PR?

Tags: git, jestjs, continuous-integration

How do I get the list of changed files after the PR has been merged to master? (the files has changed after the merge compare to before the merge - sorry if I'm not explaining it well)

**The scenario is the following:**

- a team member creating a PR that changes some test files
- the team leader will check and merged that PR into master
- After that, we detect the changed files from master and run test for only modified files. (now we run test for all files and it takes too much time)
- If all test has passed. Then the application is ready to be deploy

I'm using jest as our testing framework.

Answer (score 1):

No commit, on its own, ever *changes* **any** file.  A commit just stores a full snapshot of files.

Each commit, however, exists in the repository environment: a sea of *previous* commits.  Each of *those* commits *also* stores a full snapshot of files.  If you pick the immediate predecessor of commit *C*, for some hash ID *C*, and compare the snapshot in that predecessor—let's call it *P*, for the *parent* of commit *C*—to the snapshot in the child *C*, some file(s) will match exactly, and some will not.  The non-matching files could be called "changed".

This works really well for most commits, which have exactly one parent.  Comparing the parent's snapshot to the child's is therefore what `git log -p` or `git show` will do; this is why you *see* a commit as a change, even though it is not a change at all, but rather just a state (a snapshot, plus metadata).

Not every commit has exactly one parent, though.  A *merge commit*, in particular, is a commit with *two or more parents*.  What you *probably* want here is to compare child commit *C*, which is a merge commit, with *one* of its several parents *P<sub>1</sub>, P<sub>2</sub>, ..., P<sub>n</sub>*.  The standard `git log` or `git show` command that does this for non-merge, single-parent commits won't do the trick, because of the multiple parents: which one should it use?

Fortunately, the *order* of the *n* parents in child merge *C* is well defined: the *first* parent is the commit that was the tip of the branch before the merge, when someone or something ran:

```
git checkout somebranch
git merge <merge-arguments>
```

to produce child *C*.  So you want to have Git compare *C* against *P<sub>1</sub>*.  That's easily done:

```
$diff_command ${hash}^ ${hash}
```

(or the same with `~` or `^1` or `~1` suffixes; these all have slightly different meanings, but the meanings all collapse to "first parent" when used with no number, or with the constant 1; see [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions)).  The real tricky points here are:

- finding the commit hash `$hash`: but you must have already solved this problem, so use that solution unless it has a flaw; and
- choosing the appropriate `$diff_command`.

It's tempting to run `git diff`, but this is usually a mistake, because `git diff` is what Git calls a *porcelain* command: meant for use by users, not by programs.  You probably want a list of files that is easily digested by a program, not by a human.  Git commands that generate output formatted for use by other *programs* are called *plumbing* commands.  The diff suite of commands includes `git diff-tree`, which is probably the plumbing command you want.  The options you want may or may not include `--name-status`, `-r`, and `-z`; `--find-renames` or `-M` with some value; `--diff-filter` with specific letters; and more.  See [the `git diff-tree` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-tree) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming X is the merge commit, `git diff --name-only X^ X` will list the changed files.

If you invoke the command in the master branch just after the merge, you can use keyword `HEAD` instead of the commit hash X as `git diff --name-only HEAD^ HEAD`